# How to run a Scheduled Method in a Cluster for one Node and for All?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, cluster-computing

I have a Glassfish 3.1.2 that runs in a cluster and a EJB 3.1 application. And I need two kind of Scheduled Methods in my application:

- one kind that runs only once (on a single node) once a day
- and other kind that runs on all nodes (every 1-2 Minutes) -- They do NOT need to run a syncron way! The requirement is just that this kind run on every node.

I have no clue how to start with this cluster - problem, is this possible with `@Schedule` (and how) or do I need something else?

Comment: There is an answer to this question in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11465568/280244

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I faced the exact same issue (need one `cluster` timer and a `per node` timer) and came across this question. So, for anyone interested:

If you declare the timer with @Schedule(..., persistent=true), you will get a `cluster` timer stored in the timer db (which can be migrated)

If you declare the timer with @Schedule(..., persistent=false), you will get a `node` timer not stored in the timer db (which can't be migrated)

Comment: Is this just an observation, or is there some documentary?

Comment: @Ralph This behavior is verified on my application (running on a Glassfish 3 cluster). I can't find the exact documentation but I can explain the behavior:
If the timer is persistent in the timer database (a MySQL database in my case, you can't use the embedded db on a cluster), it shared for all nodes through the database.
For a non-persistent timer, each node has no way to know that the timer exists on other nodes, hence a new timer is created on each node.

Comment: You can also read [this](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/non-persistent-singleton-timers-clustered-environment-using-gf31)

Comment: Is this behaviour confirmed to be implemented also on JBoss / Wildfly in domain mode?

Comment: I am also facing same issue in weblogic. I have created TimerTask. I just want to run this timertask only on one node at a time. can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using JMS. For the method that needs to run on a single node, use a queue and for the ones that need to run on all nodes use a topic.